# Retrofit - Handle refresh token expiration

Tags: android, oauth, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

When my app's Access Token is expired, I use Refresh Token to get a new Access Token through Authenticator class.

My code follows:

```
if (response.code() == 401) {
   Log.d("refresh", "Access token expired")
   val webservice: Webservice = RetrofitClient.makeRetrofitService().create(Webservice::class.java)
   var refreshToken = PreferenceData.getUserLoggedInRefreshToken(App.GetContext()!!)
   var map = generateRequestBody(mapOf("refreshToken" to refreshToken!!))
   var refreshResponse = webservice.refreshToken(map).execute()

   if (refreshResponse != null && refreshResponse.code() == 200) {
      Log.d("refresh", "New access token received")
      var newToken = (refreshResponse.body() as UserLogin).token
      var refreshToken = (refreshResponse.body() as UserLogin).refreshToken
      PreferenceData.setUserLoggedInAccessToken(App.GetContext()!!, newToken)
      PreferenceData.setUserLoggedInRefreshToken(App.GetContext()!!, refreshToken)

      return response.request().newBuilder()
      .header("Authorization", "Bearer $newToken")
      .build();
    }
}
```

So far so good.
What I want to do now is when my Refresh Token is expired, I would like to redirect user to app's login screen. But my problem is, when I call

`var refreshResponse = webservice.refreshToken(map).execute()`

server also returns 401. So my problem is I cannot tell whether the 401 I received is due to Access Token being expired or Refresh Token being expired. What's the most suitable way to handle this problem?

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take a look at [AppAuth-Android](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) implementation.

1. Before doing any call you can [check that you still have a valid access token](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/blob/f1dbeb51f4d905523d804d70363abdb00728d99c/library/java/net/openid/appauth/AuthState.java#L323), getting its expiration time and comparing it with the result from `clock.getCurrentTimeMillis()`.
2. Just in case the access token is invalid for other reasons (e.g. the access token can be manually revoked), you can use an [Okhttp Interceptor](https://freakycoder.com/android-notes-58-how-to-handle-401-error-on-retrofit-112820e254b7) to react to 401s.
3. If the access token is expired or if you get a 401, you can try to [refresh the access token with your refresh token](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/blob/f1dbeb51f4d905523d804d70363abdb00728d99c/library/java/net/openid/appauth/AuthState.java#L561).
4. If the refresh token is not valid anymore, the `/token` endpoint will return the [following error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-45):

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request {   "error":"invalid_request" }

4. If you get that error, you can logout the user and send him the app's login screen.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: so it seems like I should ask the server to return 400 Bad Request so I can differentiate whether the failure is because of Access Token or Refresh Token expiration. Another thing I learned from your answer is that we shall check the validity of token on clients end first before relying on server, maybe to save api usage. thanks!

Comment: Yes, all the possible errors are defined in the [OAuth 2.0 RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749). There you can see that when the refresh token is invalid, expired or revoked the server has to return `400` and `invalid_grant` error code. About the local expiration check, it saves you from making an unnecessary network call.

Comment: @DavidMiguel the place where the expiry of access token is checked in the repo, that logic can fail  - if user changes the android time?